# Forward user to SMS application from your app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to find a way where, when a user clicks on a button, the user gets forwarded to the default built in SMS application in Windows Phone. Also when the default SMS application opens, I'd like to specify a number that should already be entered as the recipient. (So, forward user to the SMS app and also send a mobile number as a parameter).

Any tips and pointers on how to achieve this would be great! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `SmsComposeTask` with its `To` property set:

```
var smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
smsComposeTask.To = "2065550123";
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Read more at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Is there something similar to use for email functionality? e.g. getting forwarded to the default email client?

Comment: Yes, [`EmailComposeTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)